# How to get default ip address from device?

Tags: java

I need to know because when I send a broadcast packet I have no way of checking if it came from myself. My code problem is with Android it works fine on desktop. For android it keeps giving me an IPV6 but the broadcast address it gives me is normal...

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the IP address of the host.

```
private String getHostIpAddress() throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces;
    interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface current = interfaces.nextElement();
        if (!current.isUp() || current.isLoopback() || current.isVirtual())
            continue;
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = current.getInetAddresses();
        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress currentAddr = addresses.nextElement();
            if (currentAddr.isSiteLocalAddress()) 
                return currentAddr.getHostAddress();                
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code for getting the IP address of the device:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```